# How to use async/await in Javascript - Odoo

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wanted to know how to use async/await in javascript but I have no idea on using the `await`. The `installapp` function doesn't finish it's job. So this is what I did:

```
odoo.define('custom_module.custom_feature', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var session = require('web.session');

$(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){

            var database_name = $("#db_name").val();

            installapps(database_name).then(function(){
                        console.log('installed apps')
                    });

        });
    });


// it doesn't finish the process here
    async function installapps(database_name){
        var args = {db_name: database_name}
        console.log("install apps");
        return session.rpc('/custom/installapps', args)
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of `return session.rpc(...args)` try `return await session.rpc(...args)`

Comment: How you detect `function doesn't finish it's job`?

Comment: `var args = await {db_name: database_name}` try this